# QuantExt-Python installation error: No such file or directory: '../../LICENSE.TXT'

Tags: python, pip

I was installing `QuantExt` in `cmd` & `anaconda` prompt but it failed with this error code. please solve this problem.

```
C:\Users\cksgh>pip install QuantExt-Python
Collecting QuantExt-Python
  Using cached QuantExt-Python-1.8.3.3.5.tar.gz (1.0 MB)
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\cksgh\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\cksgh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3q8h8iok\\quantext-python_d408167b32cd4faa8f2deadf8d7654d3\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\cksgh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3q8h8iok\\quantext-python_d408167b32cd4faa8f2deadf8d7654d3\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\cksgh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-25m1rjsb'
         cwd: C:\Users\cksgh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3q8h8iok\quantext-python_d408167b32cd4faa8f2deadf8d7654d3\
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\cksgh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3q8h8iok\quantext-python_d408167b32cd4faa8f2deadf8d7654d3\setup.py", line 251, in <module>
        license          = codecs.open('../../LICENSE.TXT','r+',
      File "c:\users\cksgh\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\codecs.py", line 905, in open
        file = builtins.open(filename, mode, buffering)
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../../LICENSE.TXT'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traceback indicates a packaging error; it looks like `setup.py` inside the QuantExt package attempts to access a file which the author forgot to include, or misspelled the path to.

If you are handy with Python, you might be able to download the package sources and patch them; but if not, there really isn't much you can do except try to find an older version which works, or wait for an update from someone who is able to fix it and publish a new version.

Comment: https://github.com/OpenSourceRisk/ORE-SWIG/blob/master/QuantExt-SWIG/Python/setup.py#L251 looks different and possibly fixed, but I'm not entirely sure it's the same project, as some of the URLs are broken links. The version number is older than in your traceback.

Comment: thank you. i solve this problem. QuantExt can be accessed by python.3.7 and my version was 3.8 so i downgraded my anaconda python version to 3.7 creating extra space.